# How to estimate solana mintNFT cost before actually minting in web3js?

Tags: blockchain, solana, solana-web3js

This is the function when I call to this It will mint nft. But, I want to calculate the fee instead of minting. I search on the internet but everyone is talking about the fixed price of Solana transactions. I didn't get any suitable answer to calculate the transaction fee. Is it possible?

```
let signature = await metaplex.actions.mintNFT({
  connection: connection,
  wallet: new metaplex.NodeWallet(senderKeypair),
  uri: metadataUri,
  maxSupply: 10,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to get the fee for a transaction using the `getFeeForMessage` JSON RPC endpoint: https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#getfeeformessage

In your case, since you're also minting an NFT, in addition to the transaction fee, you will need to pay Rent for all of the accounts created, which includes the Token Mint, Account to hold it, Metadata account.  You can follow along everything being done at: https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex/blob/master/js/packages/web/src/actions/nft.tsx#L76

On top of the transaction and rent fees on Solana, you also need to pay ArWeave to hold your data.  You can calculate those fees at https://docs.metaplex.com/overviews/storage_overview#arweave-storage-calculator